# jquery.ajax, success and done function is not returning anything

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am a wordpress user and try to update the database using jquery.ajax. My code updates the database but the success function doesn't return anything to html div tag. Here are some portions of my code:

PHP Code:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, NAME);
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    $msg = "Connection With Database is not Successful. Error: ".mysqli_error();
    echo $msg;
    die();
}


$nam = $_POST['name'];
$eml = $_POST['email'];

$entry = "INSERT INTO `table` (name, email,) VALUES ('$nam', '$eml')";

if(!mysqli_query($connect, $entry)){
    $msg = "Error while submitting Your Data. Error: ".mysqli_error();
    echo $msg;
    die();
    }

$msg = "Your data submitted successfully";
echo $msg;

mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```

HTML Code:

```
<form method="POST" id="data_form">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" />
  <br>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" required />
  <br>
  <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

jQuery Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (){
    $("#data_form").submit(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var formdata = $("#data_form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "udata.php",
            data: formdata,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
                $("#output").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I also used 'done' instead of 'success' but didn't work.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (){
    $("#data_form").submit(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var formdata = $("#data_form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "udata.php",
            data: formdata,
            cache: false
        }).done(function(result){
                $("#output").html(result);
        });
    });
});
```

Actually I am trying to print the $msg variable from the php file to the 'output' div tag.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are there any errors in your browsers developer tools console? can you see the request/response in the developer tools network tab?

Comment: There is warning message in firefox console: "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at udata.php. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)."

Comment: interesting, since an url that's only "udata.php" by definition is in the same domain - is the code you posted "accurate", or is the url pointing to some other host?

Comment: there is website name behind the "udata.php" like www.example.com/udata.php,

Comment: well, the error you received is telling you the problem - look up CORS to see how you can fix it

Comment: Well thanks for the help #Jaromanda X